# Configure Log4J to write new file every day new log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have this basic configuration of Log4J:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogMessages.class.getName());
        BasicConfigurator.configure();  // Basic configuration for Log4J 1.x

        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
        //configure the appender
        String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
        console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN));
        console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
        console.activateOptions();
        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

        FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("log" + File.separator + "messages.log");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();

        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa); //repeat with all other desired appenders

        // BASIC TEST
        log.info("Some message  1");
        log.info("Some message  2");
        log.info("Some message  3");
        log.info("Some message  4");
```

How I can configure Log4J to create a new file everyday and write messages into the file?

Answer (score 5):

Use `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender` instead of `FileAppender`.

Details about settings can be found [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html).

### EDIT

```
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
    String conversionPattern = "[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n";
    layout.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern);

    // creates daily rolling file appender
    DailyRollingFileAppender rollingAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
    rollingAppender.setFile("app.log");
    rollingAppender.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
    rollingAppender.setLayout(layout);
    rollingAppender.activateOptions();

    // configures the root logger
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    rootLogger.addAppender(rollingAppender);

    // creates a custom logger and log messages
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(My.class);

    logger.debug("this is a debug log message");
    logger.info("this is a information log message");
    logger.warn("this is a warning log message");
```

Comment: One more question how I can set maximum log file size?

Comment: Log4j lets you roll files based on file size or date but not both. If you want size functionality on DailyRollingFileAppender you'll have to  implement it.